# Get uid of application from a list of application

Tags: android

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ListView internetapps= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

    List<PackageInfo> applist= pm.getInstalledPackages(0);

    Iterator<PackageInfo> it= applist.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()){
        PackageInfo pk= (PackageInfo)it.next();

        if(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED==(pm.checkPermission(Manifest.permission.INTERNET, pk.packageName))) //checking if the package is having INTERNET permission
        {
        myList.add(""+pk.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm));
        }

    }

    internetapps.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList));
    final TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);

    internetapps.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int list_position,long app_Uid) 
        {

            String app_selected=parent.getItemAtPosition(list_position).toString();

            final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            //get a list of installed apps.
            List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            long UID;
            //loop through the list of installed packages and see if the selected
            //app is in the list
            for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
                if(packageInfo.packageName.equals(app_selected)){
                    //get the UID for the selected app
                    UID = packageInfo.uid;
                    text1.setText("Yeah");

                }
                else {
                    text1.setText("No");
                }

            }

        }
    });

}
```

How to get uid of application from application in a list. I try to get the uid by using the above code, but it always show negative result ( I use setText to trace which the code it run in if..else...it always show "No" after i click on an item ). Anything wrong with my code.

Answer (score 2):

This is **NOT**  good way to debug this, you should be using logs. The ID that will be returned will be the ID of the application. Your logic should follow this assumption. Ensure you are fundamentlly retrieving everything you inteded to. There I nothing wrong with the API, it is more so user error.

*Also using the API is useless if you don't understand what is supposed to be returned. **READ** the documentation*.

Also, for a hint what could be wrong, my suggestion woud be to ensure that you are filling your list with what YOU want. Learn the differences between an application and a package.

getInstalledApplications(int flags)
getInstalledPackages(int flags)

Read the documentation to learn what flags is used for, and what are valid values. Your assumption of passing 0 into the agruments of your getInstalledPackages doesn't map to anything in the documenatation. Which of course a problem.

And my final piece of advice instead of assuming your values are right, check what is being compared. Be paranoid when testing code.